# jfrog artifactory as docker registry

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

We use jfrog artifactory as docker registry. One can put all their images in a single repository in a registry.( with seperate folders). Or we can create one repository for each application.

What is the recommended practice ? Do we create a

1. repository per application or  ?
2. one repository for the whole company or ?
3. something in middle and maybe several separate repositories ?

Creating separate repository per application may be a lot of work for admins ? Is there an easier way to do it ? Maybe create a CI/CD job to create and delete the repository using API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend referring to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Docker+Registry) first to understand the docker repository. Moreover, the recommendation would be based on your use case and how you would like to manage the things, though what I would recommend is instead of creating a repository each time for a specific image which is indeed a tedious task and might also cause repository name conflict later. It is better to have a single docker local repository and push the image with a folder in it. Let us take an example of pushing the ubuntu image with 1.0 as a tag to the Artifactory, therefore it will look as Artifactory --> docker-local --> ubuntu (folder name for that image) --> ubuntu:1.0

Similarly, you can have the images pushed in this manner so that the headache of managing multiple repositories will be less, and pushing images to a single repository will help manage the images as a whole.

I would also recommend referring to the [docker access methods](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-GettingStartedwithArtifactoryProOn-Prem) used by the Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is my concern for a single repository valid ?  What if two teams end up creating the same folder structure ? There is nothing  stopping from one team from proliferating their images with another team's folder structure.

Comment: There is a chance for that definitely but you can name the repositories on each team. Suppose I have 3 teams therefore I will create 3 docker local repositories as team1-docker-local, team2-docker-local, and team3-docker-local and let each team use their specific repository